# Can't save waypoints in Google maps v3

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3

I downloaded this project:

http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm

To se how to save waypoints, I opened, the html, and tryied to save the waypoint, but it don't work, I dont know if i need to do something in SQL or not, I just tryied to make it works, please help me if you had sucess to make it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

1. create a DB with the name **mapdir**
2. create a  table with the name **mapdir** inside this DB, the table should have  only 1 field named **value** with the type **text** (there is a file mapdir.sql inside the ZIP-file, you may  use it to create the table)
3. inside process.php you must edit line#5 and set the  correct values for `mysql_connect(servername,username,password)`

You also should change process.php,Line#3 to

```
@$data = $_REQUEST['mapdata'];
```

....otherwise you later will not be able to load the waypoints when `error_reporting` is on.

But however, I wouldn't suggest to use this project like it is, there isn't any protection against SQL-injection.

Comment: P-E-R-F-E-C-T GUY ! Awesome, Thank you, I want to put +1 of useful to you, but my score is under 15 =(. But I positived the answer