# How I can to pass the values lat, lng and address from jQuery function to PHP form, and save all on a table MySQL?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, latitude-longitude

How I can to pass the values lat, lng and address  from  jQuery google maps functions (gmaps.js) to main.html ?  . I want to obtain these values  and with others  - that I will get in the main html, I want to write all together on a table (markers)   of MySQL, with a save button.
Any idea? 
Thank you!!

//**gmaps.js  function

```
function update_ui( address, latLng ) {
  $('#gmaps-input-address').autocomplete("close");
  $('#gmaps-input-address').val(address);
  $('#gmaps-output-latitude').html(latLng.lat());
  $('#gmaps-output-longitude').html(latLng.lng());
  $('#gmaps-output-address').html(address);
  }
```

//**html main code:

```
<div id='input'>
      <input type='text' id='gmaps-input-address' placeholder='to start, write address...'  size="41" />
      <div id='gmaps-error'>
     </div>
</div>
    <div id="gmaps-canvas" style="width:auto; height:250px"></div>
      <p>
<!—show current lat, lng and address   -->
      Latitude: <span id='gmaps-output-latitude'></span> <br/>
      Longitude: <span id='gmaps-output-longitude'></span><br/>
      Address: <span id='gmaps-output-address'></span><br/>
……
……
<!—start form. (get others values)   -->

    <label>name<br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="name" id="name" width="100%"/>
    </label>

    <label>address<br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="address" id="precio" width="100%"/>
    </label>
    …… 
  <!—here I need to get lat and assign to var-->
  <!—here I need to get lng and assign to var -->
  <!—here I need to get address and assign to var -->
  <!— each one lat, lng , address,  in separate vars -->
  <!— call to sql to save them in a table -->
<!—end of form (get others values)    -->
```

//**SQL sentence:

```
function insertar($campos){

if($this->con->conectar()==true){
return mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers ( name, precio, lat, lng, address ) VALUES ('".$campos[0]."','".$campos[1]."','".$campos[2]."','".$campos[3]."','".$campos[4]."')");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this today !

I used [this project](http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm) as base.

Used Apache and my SQL, and done the project on dreamweaver, it's working fine ! =)

This is one post that a guy helped me to put the site online
[Can't save waypoints in Google maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474099/cant-save-waypoints-in-googls-maps-v3)

Just edit process.php to your localhost, user and pass.

Try it =)